# Three.js equivalent for Android?

Tags: android, three.js

I'm looking to build an application for Google Cardboard that is very similar to Barry Martin's Hopalong Orbits Visualizer  (http://iacopoapps.appspot.com/hopalongwebgl/) which uses three.js and only works for web browsers.

I'm not sure if I need to use OpenGL. It seems like overly complicated for my purposes. Is there any three.js equivalent for android?

Answer (score 1):

Three.js works on android,iOS and windows mobile too.
And you can "pack it" with a wrapper to run it like a native application on those devices.
For example, since I use it a lot, there's the Crosswalk project.
I don't see any problem with Three.js but if you do, here is a list of 3D engines which are using webgl:
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=webgl+engine&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

If you don't like this approach, you have to either learn OpenGL or to use a framework which is built around it; to mention a couple that I like the most: Project Anarchy,Unity.